# Converting String to Hex then into Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

So,
I have a string that I want to convert each character to hex values and then put it in a byte array to be sent through a com port.

I can convert the individual characters to the hex that I need to send, but I can't get that array of strings into a byte array correctly.

example:

```
string beforeConverting = "HELLO";

String[] afterConverting = {"0x48", "0x45", "0x4C", "0x4C", "0x4F"};
```

should become

```
byte[] byteData = new byte[]{0x48, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x4F};
```

I've tried several different things from several different posts but I can't get the right combination of things together. If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me a snippet of example code that would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your final aim is to send `byte[]`, then you can actually skip the middle step and immediately do the conversion from `string` to `byte[]` using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` (provided that you send ASCII char):

```
string beforeConverting = "HELLO";
byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(beforeConverting); 
//will give you {0x48, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x4F};
```

If you don't send ASCII, you could find the appropriate Encoding type (like Unicode or UTF32), depends on your need.

That being said, if you still want to convert the hex string to byte array, you could do something something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// To convert Hex data string to bytes (i.e. 0x01455687)  given the data type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hexString"></param>
/// <param name="dataType"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] HexStringToBytes(string hexString) {
  try {
    if (hexString.Length >= 3) //must have minimum of length of 3
      if (hexString[0] == '0' && (hexString[1] == 'x' || hexString[1] == 'X'))
        hexString = hexString.Substring(2);
    int dataSize = (hexString.Length - 1) / 2;
    int expectedStringLength = 2 * dataSize;
    while (hexString.Length < expectedStringLength)
      hexString = "0" + hexString; //zero padding in the front
    int NumberChars = hexString.Length / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
    using (var sr = new StringReader(hexString)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
byte[] byteData = afterConverting.Select(x => HexStringToBytes(x)[0]).ToArray();
```

The method I put above is more general which can handle input `string` like `0x05163782` to give `byte[4]`. For your use, you only need to take the first byte (as the `byte[]` will always be `byte[1]`) and thus you have `[0]` index in the `LINQ Select`.

The core method used in the custom method above is `Convert.ToByte()`:

```
bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
```

Comment: Yep, the first two lines you posted worked great! Couldn't thank you enough! You're a genius in my mind!

Comment: Great. Glad to know that! :)

Answer (score 2):

To convert just the hexadecimal string to a number, you could use the [System.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.100).aspx) class like so

```
string hex = "0x3B";
byte b = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(2), 16)
// b is now 0x3B
```

Substring is used to skip the characters `0x`